# Eclipses does not seem to generate the correct Blank Activity android project

Tags: android, eclipse

Hey guys I am new to Android development with eclipse. I am following the walkthrough on the google website ([here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html)) and already hit an issue with it. I've installed the SDK and eclipse as instructed. Now I am trying to create and run a default Blank Activity android app. When I create the project, eclipse creates an appcompat_v7 project along side my MyFirstApp project. When I hit run, the app seems to be build without any issues and the log tells mw that it is installed on my app. But nothing happens, and I can't find it on the device.

Now the reason I think that it is not getting generated is because that Android Manifest is very barebones and missing lots of vital things by the looks of it:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.myfirstapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
</application>
```

Secondly, the next step in the tutorial asks me to open up the fragment_main.xml file from the res/layout/ directory. This file does not exist. The directory is empty, there is nothing there.

I don't get any errors so I am not sure what has gone wrong.

Comment: try these tutorials, they are great and provide a step-by-step guidance to everything--> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SUOWNXGRc6g&list=PL2F07DBCDCC01493A&index=2

Comment: I have faced the same problem after I updated ADT. Workaround is to create the MainActivity manually. Uncheck "create activity" checkbox when configuring your new project.

Comment: Thanks @yygyt but still no luck. Am I expected to create the manifest myself? What I mean is, is the google tutorial out of date? When I follow the tutorial I expect the manifest to create itself and for the app to run (as per the tutorial). If this doesn't happen then I can't help but feel like something is wrong. I want to fix it.

Comment: No, you are not. Manifest gets created but you need to add your launcher activity within `application` tags. Tutorial not outdated but I suppose there is a bug in the newest release of the ADT bundle, I'm not sure.

Comment: 1. Uncheck "create activity" check box when configuring your new project
2. Create the package and MainActivity manually
3. Add it to the manifest.

*These are the steps I took.*

Comment: Sure that get's me past hurdle number 1. (in theory, I havn't tried it yet) But my project is missing fragment_main.xml as required in the next part of the tutorial. My concern is that if I am having these issues in the first 2 steps, I can't imagine the sort of stuff I'd be having problems with later on because my project wasn't generated correctly.

Comment: Of course. I was just talking about the part where you mentioned creating blank activity. There is this option of downgrading your ADT, but again I'm not sure if that actually is your problem. In my case, it did help.

Comment: @yygyt I have tried what you suggested. I added the activity to the manifest and the project builds/gets sent to my device correctly. However it crashes right away because I get java runtime exceptions because classes are missing from my project (Like I said, a lot of things seem to be missing)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56534/discussion-between-prodigga-and-yygyt).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a long discussion with @Prodigga, we came to the point where we think it is better to take a step back and wait for things to settle with the new SDK release (api level 21).

By the way, tutorial in the question is not outdated. There is this minor problem with the new sdk.

I don't know what is causing the problem and I don't know the solution yet but there is a workaround. If you only want to create a blank activity, given that you are experiencing the same issue, do as follows

1. Uncheck "create activity" check box when configuring your new project.
2. Create the package and MainActivity manually.
3. Add it to the manifest manually.

If you would like to benefit from code auto-generation, then I recommend downgrading the sdk. For example, you could use [this ADT bundle](http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030.zip) (10/30/2013 - Windows 64-bit), but don't try updating the SDK to level 21, not yet.

Answer (score 0):

In your android manifest file, add an activity element as the child of the application element. Add the name of the Activity class that you would want to show on the launch screen. See the below link on the syntax for this: 
http://www.mkyong.com/android/how-to-set-default-activity-for-android-application/

Comment: I am not sure what you are talking about with the elements. I am trying to trouble shoot my eclipse and figure out why it is not generating the correct default project. I don't want to manually create the manifest, I want to fix the problem and follow the Google tutorial properly.

Comment: Sorry, I had used the angle brackets around the words activity and application, which made these words disappear from the answer

Comment: Thanks. I followed the instructions. I added the activity to the manifest and the project builds/gets sent to my device correctly. However it crashes right away because I get java runtime exceptions because classes are missing from my project (Like I said, a lot of things seem to be missing). This issue seems to stem more deeply than an incorrect manifest file. There appears to be lots of things missing from the generated project.